# Cannot find problems with array based deque, but getting outOfBounds exception

Tags: java, deque

I have been trying to figure this out for an age, but to no avail. I think I must have several problems with my code that I just can't see. I have implemented this using a slightly more complex way before, and was writing it in a simpler form to help a friend in the year below me who is struggling, but I've just ended up getting myself in a muddle!

The code is as follows :

```
 public class ArrayBasedDeque<EltType> implements Deque<EltType> {

  private final int CAPACITY = 10;
  private int capacity;
  private int end;
  private EltType deque[];  

  public ArrayBasedDeque() {
    this.capacity = CAPACITY;
    deque = (EltType[]) (new Object[capacity]);  
  }
  public EltType first() {
    return  deque[0];
  }
  public EltType last() {
    return deque[end];
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return end == 0;
  }

  public int size() {
   return deque.length;
  }

  public boolean isFull() {
   int curSize = size();
   return curSize >= capacity;
  }

  public void insertFirst(EltType first) {
    if(!isEmpty()) {
    EltType[] tempArray;
    tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity+1];
    for (int i=0;i<deque.length;i++) {
      tempArray[i+1] = deque[i]; 
    }
    deque = tempArray; 
    }
   deque[0] = first;
   end++;
  }

  public void insertLast(EltType last) {
    if (isFull()){
          EltType[] tempArray;
      tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[CAPACITY+1];
      for (int i=0;i<deque.length;i++) {
        tempArray[i] = deque[i]; 
      }
    }
    deque[end] = last;   
    end++;
  }

  public EltType removeFirst() {
    EltType[] tempArray;
    EltType returned = deque[0];
    tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity];
      for (int i=1;i<capacity;i++) {
        tempArray[i-1] = deque[i]; 
      }
      deque = tempArray;
      end--;
    return returned;
  }

  public EltType removeLast() {
    EltType[] tempArray;
        System.out.println(end);
    EltType returned = deque[end];

    tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity];
      for (int i=0;i<deque.length;i++) {
        tempArray[i] = deque[i]; 
      }
      deque = tempArray;
    return returned;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I call

```
abd.insertFirst( 3 );
abd.insertFirst( 3 );
abd.insertFirst( 3 );
```

this, it returns an error.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at ArrayBasedDeque.insertFirst(ArrayBasedDeque.java:37)
    at TestABD.main(TestABD.java:7)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)
```

the same is true for the insertLast method. I can't figure it out, and was hoping the scrutinizing gaze of stackOverflow could help me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you try stepping it through in a debugger?

Comment: There a many, many logic errors in this code. It also appears to be a HW assignment. Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity+1];
for (int i=0;i<deque.length;i++) {
  tempArray[i+1] = deque[i]; 
}
deque = tempArray;
```

After the first method call, `deque` is an array of length 11 (`deque` == `tempArray`  == `new Object[capacity+1]` == `new Object[11]`.  The next time the method is called, you allocate `tempArray` for `capacity+1` == `11` slots, but traverse the for-loop from `0` to `deque.length` which is `0` to `10` on the second method call.  The last pass of the loop ends up being:

```
tempArray[11] = ...
```

which is past the end of `tempArray` which only has `11` slots (`[0]` to `[10]`).

---

The naive fix is to have the for-loop go from `0` to `capacity` instead of from `0` to `deque.length`, but I'm unsure if this implements the actual behavior you want. Another approach is to allocate `tempArray = new Object[deque.length+1]`, but then `capacity` doesn't really mean capacity and it still may not reflect conceptually what you think is the "correct" behavior in that situation.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for the explanation. I always get confused with the .length operator ! :)

Comment: @user476033 - what should happen when the deque is full and `insertFirst` is called? should the buffer always expand (in which case `capacity` is current capacity, not the capacity limit), should an item get dropped, or should the `insertFirst` fail (possibly fail silently, leaving nothing changed)?

Comment: the buffer should always expand in this case, with the item in this case being appended onto deque in position [0]. This is not currently working, however! :(

Comment: @user476033 then `capacity` is probably redundant with `deque.length`. when stuff isn't working how you expect, its good to have a good idea of what you want to happen in each method for each key case, and then walk through each method with a debugger during key cases (empty, partly full, full to capacity)  and/or use `println`s through the code to show/verify what the picture looks like before/after each method call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in Java, so I could be off base here but...when you call InsertFirst, no values been set to capacity yet. So it defaults to either 0, or junk. Either way, when you call
  tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity+1];
the capacity will either be 1 or...some 'random' number. Hence why are getting outOfBounds. I'm guessing you meant to use CAPACITY?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to that particular bug. You aren't updating the instance variable `capacity` so each time you call `insertFirst` the temp array array isn't actually growing. So the code should look like:

```
public void insertFirst(EltType first) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        EltType[] tempArray;
                       capacity += 1;
        tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < deque.length; i++) {
            tempArray[i + 1] = deque[i];
        }
        deque = tempArray;
    }
    deque[0] = first;
    end++;
}
```

Still, the overal class is far from correct.